# Xcode Crashes when adding UIViewController in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I was in Xcode and I went to edit a nib file. I tried to drag on a UIViewController from the objects library, but as soon as I did Xcode crashed. I had never had this problem before, but now I cannot add a UIViewController to the nib file (the problem persists for other files in the same project and other files in other projects).

Originally, the problem occurred in the Developer Beta of Xcode 4.5 that I was using, but now when I tried in the old version of Xcode the problem was there also.

Basically, I have been unable to find a way to get this problem to stop. If anyone has experienced this problem or knows how to fix it, that would be so great.

Thanks,
Luke

Answer (score 0):

What about trying to delete all Xcode preferences files? It seems like the latest Xcode beta broke something there...

Have a look at the following folders:

```
/Users/xyz/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode
/Users/xyz/Library/Application Support/Xcode
/Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode
/Users/xyz/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
```